# Trying to find email address but recieving 451 GL error

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to find out if a email address exists on a mail server. Here is what I have done so far:

Gets MX records:

```
nslookup -query=mx XXXXX.com
```

Connects to the mail server:

```
telnet eXXXX-1XXX1-3.iXXXXXal.com 25
```

Says hello to the mail server:

```
helo
```

Then I do:

```
mail from:<testa1@XXXX.org>
rcpt to:<testa2@XXXX.com>
```

But I get this error:

```
451 please retry later (gl)
```

Anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Please excuse my poor explanation on the problem. I am relatively new to using SMTP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MX that you are connecting to may suspect that the server that you are connecting from may not be a legitimate mail server, and therefore it is `greylisting` you.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) for more information about what greylisting is and how it works.

The cause of the problem could be as simple as the DNS for the server that you are connecting from not being set up correctly.  It may help if you specify your server's hostname in the HELO command, and make sure that the DNS for this hostname points to the IP address that you are connecting from, and make sure that this IP address has a PTR record that points back to that same hostname.